# Generating 10000 random ints betweeen -100000 and 100000

Tags: c++

I want to generate an array of `n` ints, in range `minn` to `maxx`. Everything works well when `n=10000`, `minn=0` and `maxx=100000`, but when `n=10000`, `minn=-100000` and `maxx=100000` the program only generates negative numbers.
This is the function that generates my numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int n, minn, maxx;
int* v=new int[100000000];
void generare_sir(int n, int* v, int minn, int maxx, std::string caz_particular)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        v[i]=fmod((unsigned)rand(),(maxx-minn+1))+minn;
        cout<<i<<" "<<v[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"minn=";
    cin>>minn;
    cout<<"maxx=";
    cin>>maxx;
    generare_sir(n, v, minn, maxx, caz_particular);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include the definitions of the missing variables.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/BhAkaZ)

Comment: [RAND_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX)

Comment: @Croolman for me it generates 10000 numbers that are less than 0.

Comment: I also dont see any problem.

Comment: You're asking to generate `10000 random ints` but you're declaring a **100000000-int** array, and you didn't even delete the memory after using. But why declare it as global? `caz_particular` is also redundant, and should be passed as `const std::string&` if it's read-only. Besides you're including `<random>` but use `rand()`

Comment: Two off topic suggestions: 1) Try not to use global variables and arrays, 2) using `delete` keyword, free the memory that is allocated by `new`, otherwise, it's a memory leak

Comment: I'm guessing `RAND_MAX` is not very large on your platform. You should use the c++11 random library instead of rand. E.g on visual studio it is only 0x7fff: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/rand-max?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmod((unsigned)rand(),(maxx-minn+1))+minn` will not produce good results for you.

`rand()` returns values between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. `RAND_MAX` is quite small on some platforms, for example in visual studio it is `32767`.

With `maxx-minn + 1` being `200,001`, in visual studio `rand()/maxx-minn + 1` will produce values between 0 and `0.163`. As this is not more than `1` the result of `fmod` will also be between `0` and `0.163`. Adding back in `minn` and truncating to an integer will result in `minn` every time.

You'd get a better result from:

```
v[i] = static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * (maxx-minn + 1) + minn);
```

Note however that the randomness of this would be poor, only `RAND_MAX` different numbers would be produced and the distribution of the numbers across the range would not necessarily be even.

The best solution is to use the c++11 [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library (which you are already including in your code):

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(minn, maxx);
...
v[i] = dis(gen);
```

This should give you an even distribution of good quality random numbers across your range and should work for any value of `minn` and `maxx`.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
void generare_sir(int n, int* v, int minn, int maxx)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(minn,maxx);

    generator.seed(time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        v[i] = distribution(generator);
        cout<<i<<" "<<v[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

A little explanation:
Original code has no problem except the min and max values. rand() can generate a number betweeen 0 and RAND_MAX. RAND_MAX is defined in the library as constant, and it's value is usually 32767 (0x7FFF). There is no way changing it, unless changing the library. If you substract 100000 from this random you will always get negative numbers.
You need an aleternative method for generating numbers.
For more informarion on random you can look: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/
First you create a number generator, than choose adistribution method and finally seed it.

Comment: the call to `srand` is unnecessary

Comment: A bit of explanation why this works, would be useful.

Comment: Alan Birtles, changed the srand line for randomization.